# Compiling Hadoop native - finding error in Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, ant

I'm trying to compile Hadoop and there's a Maven error in an ant plugin. I've never used Maven, or ant, and the error doesn't seem to give any indication of where the error is. The error output is at the end of the post.

I've searched the pom files for maven-antrun-plugin (there are 54 pom.xml files with that string). The error suggests it's in the one under `hadoop-common` but in that file there are several maven-antrun-plugin occurrences. I have no idea which one is the problem, and the Maven error obscures the actual error message that whatever command is failing gives.

How do I:

1. Find exactly which line is causing the error
2. Get the actual error output instead of Maven's useless error

Here's the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (make) on project hadoop-common: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 2 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (make) on project hadoop-common: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 2
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 2
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: /Users/justinmrkva/hadoop-2.2.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/antrun/build-main.xml:7: exec returned: 2
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:650)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:676)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:502)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:270)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have installed cmake in you machine. 
If you are using Ubuntu you can install cmake by using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

After installing the same, Try compiling...

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn -e -X ....
```

could help you locate the error, in particular the '-X' flag. `mvn --help`:

```
-X,--debug                        Produce execution debug output
```

It will produce quite a bit of output, though.

Comment: That output _is_ what I get from `-e -X`... there's nothing else relevant from the surrounding output.

Answer (score 0):

As @user3540568 suggests you may be running into an issue with cmake.  Once I ran into this issue I was able to scroll up through the maven output and find an error that said effectively that 'cmake' was not found in the path.  It looked like this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (make) on project hadoop-common: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmake" (in directory "/home/users/tharsch/git/hadoop-common/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/native"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
```

However, I was not running with -e or -X when I received that message.

This [blog post](http://www.csrdu.org/nauman/2014/01/23/geting-started-with-hadoop-2-2-0-building/) describes in full detail what it takes to build hadoop 2.2.0 from source.